# LinearLayout Weight Issue for large/small length text for TextViews

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 2 texview inside LinearLayout as follow:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above code assign the equal space to both textview with ellipses to text if text is large.
But In case of less length of text, there is space between both TextView.

```
{LargeTextFromTextView1... LargeTextFromTextView2...}

{TextView1TextTextVeiw2Text            }
```

How can I get rid of this with large text case handling.

Logic for showing text:

Case1: length of text of TextView1 + length of text of TextView2 <= screen width
Simply show text of both textview

Case2: length of text of TextView1 + length of text of TextView2 > screen width
text of TextView1 in first half part with ellipse and text of TextView2 in second half part with ellipse

Answer (score 0):

```
Create like this 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

Edit:

If textview should be single line and should end with ellipses use this:

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sdjhafdshfgdsfaudxzcxzcvvcvcvsfuafsdf"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ddff"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Comment: Not Working, Assign large text to first one and small text to second one. Break down

Comment: @Ajit you want ... at the end and single line textview?

Comment: Sorry not working. Please see my update question with logic for showing text.

Comment: Can you please share that demo

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tx1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sdjhatfjhgjdhhvfygkjhkkkgftddrtyrtrd"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="ddff"
        android:id="@+id/tx2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use relative layout for this requirement . If changing the layout is not a problem..
You are facing that error because you are giving weightSum, it is dividing the screen equally, therefore it doesn't matter to it if the first string length is small it just assigns the second text form its other half so ur getting the space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:lines="1"` and `android:ellipsize="end"` won't do what you are expecting. It would rather confine the text. For example, if the text is "Remove", you will see "Rem...".

To solve this problem, put each of your `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="0sp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1">
     <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:text="Text"/>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="0sp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1">
     <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:text="Text"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  use googles  **flexboxlayout**

This technique used in the example is setting the flexWrap="wrap" as explained above,

```
<com .google.android.flexbox.flexboxlayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     app:flexwrap="wrap">
```

then you can get the following layout where child views are aligned to a new line instead of overflowing its parent.

OR you should use **FlowLayout**

[FlowLayout](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5061)

A FlowLayout for Android, which allows child views flow to next row when there is no enough space. The spacing between child views can be calculated by the FlowLayout so that the views are evenly placed.

**Gradle dependency** :

```
compile 'com.nex3z:flow-layout:1.2.4'
```